# How do you find the maxima and minima on 3D surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d

I am currently learning 3D functions and their graphs.

I know that, for 2D graphs, a function $y=f(x)$ would have either a maxima or a minima at $(x,y)$ for,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Is there a similar way to find out where a 3D surface $z=f(x,y)$ has it's maxima and minima?

Comment: Do you know what partial derivatives ($\partial z/\partial x$ and $\partial z/\partial y$) are?

Comment: @Rahul Yes I do.

Comment: A differentiable function $z=f(x,y)$ has its extrema when *both* partial derivatives are zero.

Comment: @Rahul: Your statement needs to be corrected a bit. _If_ $f(x,y)$ has an extremum at a point, _then_ both partial derivatives are zero at that point. But just as in the $1$-dimensional case, the partial derivatives can be zero without $f$ having an extremum.

Comment: @JackLee You mean like a saddle point right? Like the center of a hyperbolic paraboloid (or is it parabolic hyperboloid?).

Comment: Yes. The surface you have in mind is a [hyperbolic paraboloid](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraboloid).